# Selected specific option in dropdown based on data retrieved from database(mysql) with ng-option

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs, model-view-controller

I need help with automatic selecting the option in dropdown list based on data retrieved from database. It is for editing purpose (when you editing, the data will be retrieved automatically so that you can edit). Currently, I'm able to retrieve data from database and put it in dropdown list. Btw, I'm using ng-option and the model I'm using is MVC.

```
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
        <div class="form-group" data-ng-init="companies = <?php echo htmlspecialchars(json_encode($this->companyList)); ?>">
            <label for="companyname">Company Name</label>
            <select class="form-control"  data-ng-options="c.id as c.company_name for c in companies track by c.id" id="companyname" name="companyname" data-ng-model="filter.company">
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Initially, the dropdown list will be like this

[image: Initially, the dropdown list will be like this]

The dropdown I want

[image: The dropdown I want]

Your kind assistance is much appreciated please. Thank You.

Comment: Can you show final HTML after PHP compiled

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have solved the problem already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing this

```html
<select name="repeatSelect" id="repeatSelect" ng-model="data.repeatSelect">
  <option ng-repeat="option in data.availableOptions" value="{{option.id}}">{{option.name}}</option>
</select>
```

Now whichever value you wish to show selected that must be your ng-model for `<select>` tag.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have solved the problem already with the method below

Comment: <div class="form-group" data-ng-init="companies = <?php echo htmlspecialchars(json_encode($this->companyList)); ?>">
                <label for="companyname">Company Name</label>
                <select class="form-control" id="companyname" name="companyname">
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <option data-ng-repeat="c in companies" value="{{c.id}}" <?php if(isset($this->branchListByID)){echo "ng-selected='{{c.id ==".htmlspecialchars(json_encode($this->branchListByID[0]["company_id"]))."}}'"; }?>>{{c.company_name}}</option>
 </select>
</div>

Answer (score 0):

@kelvin what is inside the "filter.company" ?, I think its a whole object and it contains company data, while in your select drop down you are setting **company.id** in the model so, i think you need to replace your **data-ng-model** with this

> data-ng-model="filter.company.id"

Hope that this will work.

Thanks